# how do I multiply each element in a list by its position in the list python

Tags: python, list, product, z-index

For example if I have 2452834, then the sum = 1x2 + 2x4 + 3x5 + 4x2 + 5x8 + 6x3 + 7x4 = 2+8+15+8+40+18+28 = 119
this is what I got I think im on the right track.

```
base_id_num = input()

n=0
for z in range (1, len(base_id_num)):
    base_id_num[n] = base_id_num[n] * n
    n+=1

print(base_id_num)
```

Comment: You have to convert the extracted single digit to int to execute the expected multiplication and you can't store the result in `base_id_num[n]` but need a new list or a variable in which you add up the sum.

Comment: `print(sum(i * int(n) for i, n in enumerate(input(), 1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're passing in a string, this can be done similarly to how you're doing it, but zero-indexing your string indices:

```
base_id_num = input()
result = 0
for i in range(len(base_id_num)):
    result += i * int(base_id_num[i])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are taking input as a string.

Instead of creating a new variable and accessing the item by index, you can use the built-in function enumerate() for this task.

```
result = 0
base_id_num = input()
for index,item in enumerate(base_id_num):
   result += int(item) * index
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comp, and built-in sum() function:

```
b = list(base_id_num) #assuming the base_id_number is of type str

result = sum(int(i) * (id+1)  for id, i in enumerate(b))
```

output:

```
print(result)
119
```

Comment: No need to convert `base_id_num` to a `list` before enumerating it.

Comment: Fair enough. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`, which will provide you with index (at index 0) and value (at index 1). After which, use `map` to multiply these two indexes (adding one to index as per your requirement) and finally `sum` them

```
sum(map(lambda x: (x[0]+1) * int(x[1]), enumerate(input())))
```

for 2452834, this will give you

> 119

I did a quick time benchmark for 2 approaches provided here, it seems that the comment from @Samwise is still the fasted

```
 %timeit sum(map(lambda x: (x[0]+1) * int(x[1]), enumerate(str(2452834))))
```

> 100000 loops, best of 5: 3.22 µs per loop

```
  %timeit sum(i * int(n) for i, n in enumerate(str(2452834), 1))
```

> The slowest run took 4.67 times longer than the fastest. This could
> mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 100000 loops, best
> of 5: 2.58 µs per loop

**Update based on benchmarks**: starting enumerate from 1, like @samwise improve things a bit,

```
%timeit sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * int(x[1]), enumerate(str(2452834),1)))
```

> The slowest run took 4.98 times longer than the fastest. This could
> mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 100000 loops, best
> of 5: 2.92 µs per loop

Answer (score 0):

Hi brother @DAN_ET you gave a fair answer and a little too optimized. So I allowed myself to offer a more detailed solution in order to facilitate our friend's understanding.

```
base_id_num: str = "2452834"
input_len = len(base_id_num) + 1
som: int = 0
echo = ""
incr = 0

for i in range(1, input_len):
   incr = i - 1 
   som += i * int(base_id_num[incr])
   echo += f'{i}x{int(base_id_num[incr])} +'
print(som)
```